# NullPointerException in case of Static reference variable

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Getting NullPointerException, c1 is initialized in main method and is later accessed in class2, but i am getting NullPointerException

```
public class Test
{
    static Class1 c1;
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        c1 = new Class1();    //c1 is initialized, still null pointer exception
    }  
}

public class Class1 
{
    int a,b;
    Class1()
    {
        class1();
    }
    void class1()
    {
        a = 5;
        b = 10;
        Class2 class2 = new Class2();
    }
}

public class Class2 
{
    Class2()
    {
        Class1 c = Test.c1;         //c1 is null here
        System.out.println(c.a);    //NullPointerException for Test.c1
        System.out.println(c.b);
    }
}
```

Comment: "Later accessed" - no, accessed **before**.  Step through with a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

To assign the value of Test.c1, you first need to construct **completely** an instance of Class1.

However, when you are constructing Class1, you call Class2 constructor into the class1() method, which in turns prints some stuff. At this point, you still didn't fully construct the Class1 instance, as a consequence, Test.c1 is not yet initialized

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly straightforward:

1. When `Test` is loaded, `c1` gets its default value `null`.
2. `main` gets called by the `java` tool.
3. `main` calls `Class1`'s constructor.

   1. `Class1`'s constructor calls `class1`.

      1. `class1` calls `Class2`'s constructor.

         1. `Class2`'s constructor tries to dereference `Test.c1`, which is `null`, so it throws.

It would only be once that nested series completed that `c1` would receive a value. But since the code tries to use it before it has a (non-`null`) value, it fails.

Stepping through the code with a debugger can make this stuff dramatically clearer. Using a debugger is not an advanced skill, it's crucial for beginners, as a learning tool for what happens when.